# Java Calendar Date Check

Tags: java

Recently I have received a mail which says that December, 2012 is a peculiar month. This month has got five saturday(s), five sunday(s) and five monday(s). Also it says that this will happen once in some 700 years only. So, I need to check that within 2000 to 2100 how many months will have five saturdays, sundays and mondays respectively.

Can this be acheived through java (especially using Calander API)?

Any ideas with sample code would be apprecialble.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For any month to have 5 of (Saturday, Sunday, Monday) it must:

- Have 31 days (4 full weeks and three extra days)
- Start on a Saturday (the three days at the end must be the fifth Saturday, Sunday, Monday)

Both of those checks should be fairly easy in even the fundamentally-broken `java.util.Calendar` API. (Prefer [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) wherever you get the choice.) If you have trouble implementing one of them, you should post a *specific* issue, showing us how far you've got so far.

Comment: There are months that are having 5 Saturdays with less then 31 days. Also the rule to start on a Saturday is not mandatory also. See my answer.

Comment: But if the OP needs to have all of Saturday..Monday five times then the rules are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Please check code below:

```
/**
 * Print all the months which has five Mondays, Saturdays and Sundays
 * @param from year from
 * @param to year to
 */
public void printMonths(int from, int to) {
    List<String> monthList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int year =from; year<=to;year++) {
        monthList.addAll(getMonth(year));
    }

    for (String s : monthList) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

/**
 * Get month with five sundays, saturdays and mondays
 * @param year
 * @return
 */
private List<String> getMonth(int year) {
    List<String> monthList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
        if (check(year, month)) {
            monthList.add("" + year + "-" + (month+1));
        }
    }
    return monthList;       
}

private boolean check(int year, int month) {
    return checkFiveDays(year, month, 1) && checkFiveDays(year, month, 2) 
    && checkFiveDays(year, month, 7);

}

private boolean checkFiveDays(int year, int month, int dayOfWeek) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    int times = 0;
    do {
        if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == dayOfWeek) {
            times++;
        }
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    } while (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)== month);

    return times == 5;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually for a month to have 5 of (Saturday, Sunday or Monday) it's not necessary to have 31 days, see September 2012 (even February on certain leap years like 2020 can have 5 Saturdays).
Not even for the month to start on that day, see: March 2013, for Saturday case.
Using Joda it's simple to count all such cases, between 2000 and 2100, like:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateParser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy");                                                            
DateTime startDate = dateParser.parseDateTime("2000");                                                                       
DateTime stopDate = dateParser.parseDateTime("2100");                                                                        
DateTime date = startDate;                                                                                                   
DateTime lastInMonth;                                                                                                        
if (date.getDayOfWeek() != DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY)                                                                       
    date = date.plusWeeks(1).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY);                                                      
int count = 0;                                                                                                               
while (date.isBefore(stopDate)) {                                                                                            
    if (date.getDayOfWeek() != DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY) //if it's not starting on Saturday                                
        date = date.plusWeeks(1).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY); //jump to the first Saturday                     
    lastInMonth = date.plusWeeks(4); //jump 4 weeks                                                                          
    if (date.getMonthOfYear() == lastInMonth.plusDays(2).getMonthOfYear()) { //check if we are still on the same month       
        count++;                                                                                                             
        // System.out.println("date = " + date); //uncomment to see each such month                                             
    }                                                                                                                        
    date = date.plusMonths(1); //advance a month                                                                             
    date = date.withDayOfMonth(1); //start on the first day                                                                  
}                                                                                                                            
System.out.println("Between " + startDate + " and " + stopDate + " there are " + count + " months that have five Saturdays");
```

`once in some 700 years only` it's not quite true, even if we count only the December months.

Comment: To have five Saturdays *and* five Sundays *and* five Mondays you absolutely must have 31 days in the month. That's what the question requires. Your code just shows any month with five Saturdays, which isn't the same thing at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet Because I used `date.getMonthOfYear() == lastInMonth.plusDays(2).getMonthOfYear()` it will check if next Monday, after the fifth Saturday, is in the same month.

Comment: @JonSkeet Initially I was counting only the 5 Saturday case, but after noticing that the user needs all of them to be five times, I updated my answer. I would appreciate if you could explain what I'm missing, in the current implementation.